# Realizar consulta utilizando ComboBox para intervalos de tempo

Tags: sql, variáveis, combobox, cast

Bom dia, pessoal.

Estou tentanto realizar uma consulta que me trará as quantidades de pacientes triados por Especialidade e por Classificação de Risco e a consulta vem funcionando sem problemas.

Contudo, gostaria de especificar ainda mais a consulta separando ela por turnos do dia (Manhã, das 07h as 12h59; Tarde, das 13h as 18h59; Noite, das 19h as 06h59)

Consegui especificar os turnos pelo código, mas eu queria que isso pudesse ser selecionado pelo usuário ao exportar o relatório através de um ComboBox, mas tô tendo problemas para fazê-lo. O código que tenho hoje é como segue:

```
    #p1;{type="date";title="Data inicial"}
    #p2;{type="date";title="Data final"}
    
    Select 
         Prioridade->Descricao as Prioridade,    
         Atendimento->Atendimento->Especialidade->Descricao as Especialidade,
         Count(*) as Total
    from 
        WClaRisco.Classificacao
    Where
         Atendimento->DataAtendimentoMedico between :p1; and :p2;
         and Hora between CAST('07:00' AS TIME) and CAST('12:59' AS TIME)
    group by
        Prioridade, Atendimento->Atendimento->Especialidade
```

O que eu havia pensado em um primeiro momento seria colocar no Where um `and Hora between :p3;` e lá no ComboBox colocar os códigos do CAST, mas sempre tenho um erro como retorno.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: *" e lá no ComboBox colocar os códigos do CAST"* não faça isso, frontend não pode nem deve ter relações com coisas de banco de dados... coloque no combo valores como 1,2,3, e no teu código de acordo com o valor, defina na query os intevalos de horas no between

Answer (score 0):

A solução que consegui pro problema:

```
     and Hora between :p3; and CASE
     WHEN :p3; = 1 THEN CAST('06:59' AS TIME) --Madrugada
     WHEN :p3; = 25200 THEN CAST('12:59' AS TIME) --Manhã
     WHEN :p3; = 46800 THEN CAST('18:59' AS TIME) --Tarde
     WHEN :p3; = 68400 THEN CAST('23:59' AS TIME) --Noite
     WHEN :p3; = 0 THEN CAST('23:59' AS TIME) --Todos     
     END
```

Assim o usuário seleciona a hora de início no ComboBox e a depender da hora de início selecionada o código vai entrar no Case e selecionar a hora fim da busca.